# Redshift 'Like' Or '=' Operator Preference

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to find some information around query optimization given **like** and **=** operators in the Where clause of my Redshift search. The example query is below:

```
Select Event, substring(regexp_substr(message, 'Segment=[A-Za-z0-9]*', 1), 9) as 
Segment,
messagetime
from Logs
where message like '%JobType=ProcessVideoSegmentIntoFragmentsJob%'
and (Status='Ingested' OR Status='Started')
and message like '%.ts%'
and messagetime >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
```

Regarding the Where clause, I am curious in which order the comparisons will be made, specifically the *Status=* and the *message like*. Since the like operator in this case is much less performant, I would hope that it was being compared *after* the **Status=**. I did an EXPLAIN on the query which is posted below:

```
XN Seq Scan on logs  (cost=0.00..48973188.14 rows=1 width=692)
Filter: (((message)::text ~~
'%JobType=ProcessVideoSegmentIntoFragmentsJob%'::text) AND (((status)::text =
'Ingested'::text) OR ((status)::text = 'Started'::text)) AND (messagetime >=
'2015-09-26 16:19:56'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((message)::text ~~ 
'%.ts%'::text))
```

As far as I can tell, since no indexes are utilized, the query will just execute on what it thinks will be most performant, but if this is the order in which it is being executed, it is most certainly not the best query plan.

Ultimately I just need to know whether Redshift will run a **like** or **=** operator first.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Redshift does not use indexes. Instead, it processes data in parallel across multiple nodes and takes advantage of data distribution (`DISTKEY`) and data sort order (`SORTKEY`).

Therefore, it is likely evaluation those expressions for *every row* of the data (but this can be reduced if a `WHERE` condition is in the `SORTKEY`).

A common technique in SQL performance improvement is to eliminate as many rows as possible within a nested `SELECT`. This is the only way to make all SQL databases evaluation values in a particular order. (Some databases have additional capabilities in this area, but they are not generic to SQL.) Therefore, you could try putting your `Status=` check into a sub-query.

See Redshift documentation: [Subquery Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Subquery_examples.html)